# Maven package only includes file in second run

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am creating a non-java Maven artifact. In the `pom.xml` I resolve some dependencies and then run a custom script using `exec` plugin. Some files are created in a directory, but Maven does not see them when packaging them in a jar.

When I run `mvn package` twice, the second run does include the resource files in the jar.

Any ideas why this is happening? The script is run during the `compile` phase, so the files are already created when the `package` phase is creating the jar.

---

This is the relevant (hopefully) part of my `pom.xml` configuration:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>build-plugin</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>bash</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>build_plugin.sh</argument>
                        <argument>${workspace}</argument>
                        <argument>${plugin}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/${outputPath}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>target/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

All the variables and paths are valid, on the second run I am getting a jar with expected content. But not during the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in maven Default Lifecycle the processing of resources happens before compiling
see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference

What you have to do is changing the build phase of the "exec-maven-plugin", use "generate-sources" instead of "compile"

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>build-plugin</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>bash</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>build_plugin.sh</argument>
                        <argument>${workspace}</argument>
                        <argument>${plugin}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/${outputPath}</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>target/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```